# group by username and select sum of column

Tags: sql, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

i have a table T like this id,username,points
and what i want to do is for each user select his username and sum of his points and order the rows by points.
i tried this but it didnt work:

```
SELECT username, sum(points) as s
FROM T
    group by username,points
    order by points desc
```

result:

```
username  points
3         2
3         3
3         0
4         0
6         0
7         0
3         -1
```

Comment: @Rachid.... The reason to remove points from the Group By is because, if you Group By points, each individual value is grouped on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're aggregating on points you don't want to include points in your GROUP BY statement. Also if you're renaming your sum of points to s you can just references s in your ORDER BY

```
SELECT username, sum(points) as s
FROM T
group by username
order by s desc
```

Comment: @Rachid....note that Matt removed points from the Group By.

Comment: yeah thanks ^^, i'll accept Matt's answer in 10 min

Answer (score 0):

The reason to remove points is becaues if you Group By points, each individual value is grouped on:

```
SELECT username, sum(points) as s
FROM T
group by username
order by sum(points) desc
```

Then order on Sum(points)